# How to delete duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble removing duplicates from an array that I have populated with random integers. I have written a java class to generate the random numbers and in my main program I have called these random numbers which write these to a .txt file. I am then to read in from this .txt file and store them in a new array removing any duplicates. Next I have to re write the new set of random numbers to a new .txt file with the smallest number on the first line and the largest last. So order in the new list doesn't matter.

My problem is I'm not sure how to remove the duplicates. I can see from other questions posted that people are saying to use Set or hashset but I have studied these yet. So is there another way of removing them by looping through the array or something?

```
import java.io.*;
class MainProg{

    public static void main (String[]args){

        GenKeys keys = new GenKeys();

        //System.out.println(keys.getrandom());
        //System.out.println(keys.getrandom());

        try{
                    String f = "keys.txt";
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                    for (int i=1; i<=500; i++){
                        //bw.write(i+ System.getProperty("line.separtor"));
                        bw.write(keys.getrandom() + "\r\n");
                    }

                    // close the file after all the writing has taken place
                    bw.close ();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println ("Error writing to file" + e.toString());
        }


            // declare a place to store each line as it is read in
            String str;
            String myArray[] = new String [500];
            int i = 0;

                try{
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("keys.txt");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    // read in the first line from the file
                    str = in.readLine();
                    while(str!=null){

                    myArray[i] = str;

                    str = in.readLine();
                    i++;
                    }

                    // close the file
                    in.close();
                    }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.print(e.toString());
                    System.out.print("Non-Existant File");
        }
            int [] mySortedArray = new int [500];
            for(int k = 0; k<mySortedArray.length;k++){
                for(int j = 0;j<mySortedArray.length;j++){
                    if(mySortedArray[j] != k){
                        mySortedArray[k] = j;
                        System.out.print(mySortedArray[k]);
                    }

            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: as it is for class you should order your array then you should remove the duplicates. it is what your teacher expects from you.

Comment: timport java.util.Random;

public class GenKeys{
 Random random;

 public GenKeys(){

 random = new Random();

}
public int getrandom(){
 return random.nextInt(250)+ 1;

}

}

Comment: Your teacher is analysing your mental ability to solve problems with the tools that you hold. So think about and don't answer others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest possible way to remove dupes uses a `LinkedHashSet`. Because this type of `Set` is designed to jump straight to the value by hashing, it will not add two value references to the same hash index.

Basically, when you try to add the same item n times, all operations after the first one will fail silently. What you get back is a duplicate free array.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for (Integer item : arr) {
        tmp.add(item);
    }
    int[] output = new int[tmp.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer item : tmp) {
        output[i++] = item;
    }
    return output;

};
mySortedArray = removeDuplicates(mySortedArray);
```

Comment: Is `int output = new int[tmp.size()];` right? Should it not be `int [] output = new int[tmp.size()];`, since you're saying `output[i++]`?

Comment: You're welcome. I suggested the edit but it wasn't updated so I thought I'd ask in case I was missing something. :)

Comment: Is linkedhashset faster than hashset?

Comment: AFAIK, no - keeping a linked list around should have additional costs. Also, this is not faster than sorting + removing neighboring duplicates (unless the number of duplicates is truly large)

Answer (score 3):

Time-wise, **O(nlogn)** is your best bet, through: **Converting the `array` into `Set` and then convert it back:**

```
Integer[] withDups = {1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7};
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(withDups));
Integer[] withoutDups = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(withoutDups));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

A set (as the set in math) is a data structure that allows no duplicate items.

If you have trouble converting from `int[]` to `Integer[]` and back, use a loop:

```
int[] intArray = ...;

Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[intArray.length];
int i = 0;
for (int value : oldArray) {
    integerArray[i++] = Integer.valueOf(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must use an array, then the easiest thing to do would be to check that the number isn't a duplicate before you add it (by looping through the array, checking if your newly generated random number is equal to any value in the array, and only adding it to the end of the array if it is.)

However, others are right when they suggest the use of a HashSet for this scenario, which prevents duplicates by design (and you get this checking for free.) It's not complicated, a basic use could be something like:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.put(1);
set.put(3);
set.put(5);
set.put(3);
for(int num : set) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

...which will print 1, 3 and 5. You'd do well to read up on and study HashSets since they're a basic, very frequently used data structure (probably the second most used structure to lists.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorting and removing duplicates, without using anything but arrays, assuming that the array is **not empty** (if empty, the correct answer is to return another empty array):

```
// sort the input
Arrays.sort(input);

// count unique elements in input
int unique=1;
for (int i=1; i<input.length; i++) {
   if (input[i] != input[i-1]) unique ++;
}

// create an output array of that size
int output[] = new int[unique];

// store unique copies of the (sorted) input elements
output[0] = input[0];
for (int i=1, j=1; i<input.length; i++) {
   if (input[i] != input[i-1]) output[j++] = input[i];
}
```

If we had been free to use `ArrayList`, the code would have been cleaner: no need to do a first pass to find out the size and a second pass to fill things in. Unless there are many duplicates, this code is significantly faster than using sets of any kind, as there is no look-up involved.